# Is there a place where you can play strong bots online?

Tags: texas-hold-em

I'd like to play against strong bots to practice, but so far I haven't found much.

I've seen http://www.cleverpiggy.com/nlbot, but it looks like it only allows heads-up. Ideally I'd like to practice 6-max no limit hold'em games.

Alternatively, I'm open to installing/compiling open-source software. I don't care how ugly it looks or if I have to play in the terminal :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only recently (about a year ago) they have created an AI called pluribus that can play and consistently win against strong human opponents in 6-max games. My guess is that it is not yet available as open source software or as something publicly available for anyone to play against because the AI was developed in a research lab at Carnegie Mellon University.

Having said that, The AI will most likely make its way into software or other commercial platforms in the near future for players to experiment with because its abilities would be very useful for players to study.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think people would pay for such a service?

Comment: They would, and they do! pokersnowie is a coaching software that utilizes AI to analyze your game (heads up I believe). You play the AI and it coaches you when you play. If there was an AI software that utilized 6-max games it would definitely get some attention and downloads. @static_rtti

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing against a 6-max bot called PokerAlfie. There is even a app for android system. Jonathan Little has a video which he is playing against it. You can visit the site and take a look: http://www.pokeralfie.com/

The link to the video where Jonathan Little is playing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8D_Wv2NZgg

Answer (score 0):

Poker.com back in the day before the domain sold, was an IRC for poker bots although their domain is gone I think they still do an irc channel for poker bots to compete. andd there maybe a link to the channel you msy also try rec.gambling poker to find poker bot info if you know how to use the old news readers anf IRC channels
I was able to find this [linkhttps://www.conjelco.com/faq/ircpoker.html#:~:text=IRC%20poker%20is%20a%20real-time%20network%20poker%20game,of%20both%20bankroll%20and%20earning%20rate%20inspire%20competitiveness.](https://www.conjelco.com/faq/ircpoker.html#:%7E:text=IRC%20poker%20is%20a%20real-time%20network%20poker%20game,of%20both%20bankroll%20and%20earning%20rate%20inspire%20competitiveness.) good luck